# Swi Prolog script not execute correctly

Tags: file, prolog

I want to read a file and then write another according to the results of the first, but once I read the first file, the program terminates immediately. I have searched for the cause of why it happens, but I have not found anything. I would like to know if someone can help me.

This is the code:

```
main :-
   current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),
   [H|_T] = Argv,
   readPlainText(H),
   getList(L), 
   open('result.txt',write,X),
   write(X, L), nl(X),
   close(X),
   halt.
main :-
   halt(1).
```

And the script stops after execute this piece of code:

```
readPlainText(X) :-
   open(X, read, Stream),
   readWords(Stream),
   close(Stream).
```

I am executing from console:

```
swipl -s leer.pl --quiet menciones.txt
```

**EDIT:** I think the problem is for at_end_of_stream

```
readWords(InStream) :-
   \+ at_end_of_stream(InStream),
   readWord(InStream, W),
   write(W), nl,
   addWordToDatabase(W),
   readWords(InStream).
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the recursion termination. Try

```
readWords(InStream) :-
  (   \+ at_end_of_stream(InStream)
  ->  readWord(InStream, W),
      write(W), nl,
      addWordToDatabase(W),
      readWords(InStream)
  ;   true
  ).
```

Or you can keep unchanged your readWords/1, and add - after it - the handler for EOF:

```
readWords(_InStream).
```

Then you could test for errors possibily occurring in readWords/1 goals (for instance, in addWordToDatabase/1), that currently would stay hidden.